# Impossible to index front chain ring!

Tags: road-bike, gears

My chain is struggling to get onto the big chain ring and when it does it has quite a bit of chain rub.

The limit screws are quite literally on the limit! And there doesn't appear to be a barrel adjuster.

I tried loosening the cable bolt and pulling on the cable to tighten but it didn't seem to have anymore to give.

Anyone have any advice?

Chain on small cog on rear cassette.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a better picture of the upper part? Are you sure the cable is attached in the right way?

Comment: Sam, can you read off the part number?  Should be something like   FD-4502 and will be stamped into the metal, probably on the parallelogram.

Comment: Did you mix the limit screws up? You’ve got the low screw fully out while the high screw is still in.

Comment: Could just be an optical illusion, but both sides of the FD cage look bent to me.  I'd fix the cable routing as described by swifty and if that doesn't work i'd personally bend the inner plate in by ~1mm

Answer (score 5):

It does look like the cable has missed the channel it should come up through the mechanism vertically, i.e. it is at the yellow arrow but should be at the blue arrow aperture (if I'm identifying the cable correctly):

[image]

Little differences like that often mean that the force is incorrect, or that the cable is restraining the movement of the derailleur.  If it's otherwise correctly routed, you might get enough slack another way, to guide it into the open aperture i.e. by moving the derailleur out by hand. Superglue is quite effective at tidying up a frayed cable if you need to re-route it. Twist it so neat and then dab in superglue. Not too much glue tho or it's too bulky.

Double check the support screw is doing work against the plate as well.

Shimano [tech doc](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-RAFD001-02-ENG.pdf) extract:

[image]

If you haven't made use of the Shimano Dealers' Manual then give it a study. Set up on this style is quite different to traditional designs. There is even a mark to show when cable tension is correct and advice on which trim position to use for setting the high limit.

There is a kind of in-buit barrel adjuster, that outward facing Allen bolt on the top assembly. I think you would loosen it off when the cable is undone and once cable is in again, tighten the bolt to add tension.

Comment: +1, question has all the markings of someone trying to adjust a knuckle FD like a traditional one. The one thing I will add is you can cause additional problems routing the cable under the adjuster as seen in the pic, because when it's down there it can get in the way of the pivots closing on the low end.

Comment: Does anyone think his limit screws are out of whack? Full out L screw and full in H screw. Might not get onto the big ring even if the cable is routed correctly.

Comment: @Jeff My suspicion too. Made that mistake once too.

Comment: @Jeff on these types of derailleur, turning the H screw in fully allows maximum outboard travel, it's the reverse of traditional designs. Good shout but OP appears to have the limits on their 'loosest' settings as part of trouble shooting.

Comment: @Swifty I see. Thanks for the info.  Guess I'll have to bone up on the more recent dealer's manuals.